# Unpivoting ranges to generate report-like results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm facing a problem to create a SQL query which uses some bins, or ranges.

I have a table, which looks like this:

```
Id  Value  Range
1   101    >100
2   8      >5
3   330    >100
4   230    >100
5   8      >5
6   101    >100
7   8      >5
8   330    >100
9   230    >100
10  8      >5
```

I can then do an aggregation query with a count to group by Range, getting then something like this(the dots are to not mess up the format):

```
Range  Total 
.>100  6 
.>5    4
```

However, what I want is something like a report, which would look like this:

```
Range  N1   P1     N2   P2  
Total  10   100%    
.>5    4    40%    6    60% 
.>100  6    60%    4    40%
```

What I've done was to remove the group and do an outter select which sums these columns in the way I want, and the unpivoted them, but I only managed to do that by using the range and N1 column, so it looks like this:

```
Range  N1     
Total  10     
.>5    4    
.>100  6
```

The query I used(before unpivoting) was:

```
select [.>5] = sum(case when ([Range] > '>5' then 1 else 0 end)
[.>100] = sum(case when ([Range] > '>100' then 1 else 0 end)
[Total] = count(*)
From tableName
```

How can I make my results look like this:

```
Range  N1   P1     N2   P2  
Total  10   100%    
.>5    4    40%    6    60% 
.>100  6    60%    4    40%
```

Note: I'm not bound to unpivoting, that's just one way I found out on how to do it, there is probably better ways i believe.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your results seem highly redundant.  Ignoring the "Total" row, you seem to want these results:

```
select Range, count(*) as n1,
       count(*) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as p1,
       sum(count(*)) over () - count(*) as n2,
       1 - count(*) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as p2
From tableName
group by [Range];
```

You can add the total using `grouping sets`:

```
select Range, count(*) as n1,
       count(*) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as p1,
       sum(count(*)) over () - count(*) as n2,
       1 - count(*) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) over () as p2
From tableName
group by grouping sets ((), ([Range]));
```

Comment: The results of this query is not quite what is expected, only the N1 column being correct, which is basically a normal group by. The results are supposed o be redundant. You gave me some ideas though, thanks!

Comment: @angra . . . Ooops, that should have been `sum(count(*)) over ())`.

Comment: That will do it! With this I'm almost there. What should I do if I want to aggregate the upper ranges? Meaning, everyone that is >100 is also >5, so the total of range >5 would be something like count(">5") + count(">100")

Comment: @angra . . . That doesn't appear to be the question you asked.  Could you ask another question, with appropriate sample data, desired results, and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello Angra may be this code help you, I check your scenario it return result what you expect.**

select [Range]='>5', N1=sum(case when ([Range] = '>5') then 1 else 0 end), P1=concat(sum(case when ([Range] = '>5') then 1 else 0 end),'0%')
, N2=sum(case when ([Range] = '>100') then 1 else 0 end), P2=concat(sum(case when ([Range] = '>100') then 1 else 0 end),'0%') from tableName

union

select [Range]='>100', N1=sum(case when ([Range] = '>100') then 1 else 0 end), P1=concat(sum(case when ([Range] = '>100') then 1 else 0 end),'0%')
, N2=sum(case when ([Range] = '>5') then 1 else 0 end), P2=concat(sum(case when ([Range] = '>5') then 1 else 0 end),'0%') from tableName

union

select [Range]='Total', N1=count(value), P1=concat(count(value),'0%'), null, null from tableName

Comment: This would solve it, but it's not very practical because I have way more ranges to consider(made it smaller for the sake of posting). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (Id int, Value int,  Range varchar(5))
insert into @t values
(1,   101,   '>100' ),
(2,   8  ,    '>5' ),
(3,   330,    '>100'),
(4,   230,    '>100'),
(5,   8  ,    '>5'),
(6,   101,    '>100'),
(7,   8  ,    '>5'),
(8,   330,    '>100'),
(9,   230,    '>100'),
(10,  8  ,    '>5')

select  CASE
        WHEN T.RANGE = '>0' THEN 'Total'
        else t.range
        end as Range,
        t.n1,t.p1,
        isnull(cast(t.n2 as varchar(6)),'') n2,
        ISNULL(cast(t.p2 as varchar(6)),'') p2
from
(
select  s.range,
        s.n1, 
        cast(cast(s.n1 as decimal(10,2))  / (select count(*) from @t) *100 as decimal(10,2)) p1,
        case 
            when s.range <> '>0' then (select count(*) from @t where range <> s.range)
        end as n2,
        case 
            when s.range <> '>0' then 
                cast(
                cast((select count(*) from @t where range <> s.range) as decimal(10,2)) /
                cast((select count(*) from @t) as decimal(10,2)) *100.00
                as decimal(10,2))
        end as p2
from
(
select t.range,count(*) n1
from    @t t
group   by range 
union  
select  '>0',count(*)
from    @t
) s
) t
order by cast(replace(range,'>','') as int)
```

result

```
Range n1          p1                                      n2     p2
----- ----------- --------------------------------------- ------ ------
Total 10          100.00                                         
>5    4           40.00                                   6      60.00
>100  6           60.00                                   4      40.00
```